# How to containerize a .net core app that has dependencies in the same solution?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, .net-core

I am trying to containerize a simple .net core console application that depends on a .net Standard library.

My solution layout is like this:

```
+
|- Solution.sln
|- Library
|  +- Files in Library project
+- App
   |- Files in App
   +- Dockerfile
```

`App` depends on `Library`.

So far I have something like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy fsproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.fsproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

But this, obviously, only containerizes `App`.

How do I achieve putting `Library` in, too, without having to put the Dockerfile into the root besides the solution file?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Anything that `docker` needs to access needs to be in the directory where `Dockerfile` is or a sudirectory of where the `Dockerfile` is. You can't access parent directories from a `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the docker build context to the parent directory.

Change your dockerfile to this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy fsproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY App/*.fsproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY App/. ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

And then run (from the folder containing Add and Library)

```
docker build -f App/Dockerfile .
```

But yes, it's usually more common to have your dockerfile located where you want your build context to be. So at the location that has all the files you'll need.

On docker for Mac/Windows the docker daemon will copy every file from the build context into the VM. So there is a performance hit here. Something to consider when you're structuring your projects.

Comment: So the better approach would be having multiple Dockerfiles if further apps are added and calling them `Dockerfile-App1`, `Dockerfile-App2` in the root etc.?

Comment: yes, although I more commonly see App1.Dockerfile App2.Dockerfile

If this answers your question please accept/upvote.

Comment: Then I will organize my Dockerfiles this way. I could also set up a dummy .net Standard Class Library with nothing inside but the Dockerfiles (so it appears in my Visual Studio solution) and put the Dockerfiles in there. Then I can use `docker build -f Dockerfiles/App1.Dockerfile`